# Python While loop being ignored

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm a student of python and i was developing this code to calculate all the combination possibilities for the 3 'A' to '9' until the OriginalArray become iqual to the PerfectArray...but for some reason the while loop doesn't stop..Anyone know why? Thanks for the help :D

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

OriginalArray = ['1','A','A','A']

def CombineLastThree(Array):
    values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

    for a in values:
        Array[1] = a
            for b in values:
            Array[2] = b
            for c in values:
                Array[3] = c
                print (Array)

def Run(Array):
    PerfectArray2 = ['2','A','A','A']

    while Array != PerfectArray2:
        CombineLastThree(Array)
        if Array[1] == '9' and Array[2] == '9' and Array[3] == '9':
            Array[1] = 'A'
            Array[2] = 'A'
            Array[3] = 'A'
            Array[0] = int(Array[0]) + 1

Run(OriginalArray)
```

Comment: With no specific python knowledge at all, my first doubt would be – can you compare two arrays for “equalness” using the `!=` operator in python?

Comment: It was my first doubt as well, i saw some post here on this site and it seemed to me that it was possible. If i change the "while Array != PerfectArray2" to "while Array[1:] != PerfectArray[1:]" the cycle doesn't even begin which it is suppose to happen.  So i think yeah the != operator is working. I already tried the cmp() function which doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @CBroe: That depends on what you mean by "arrays".  In this case, the objects in question are not arrays; they're lists.

Comment: In the future; strategically placed print statements/functions can often give you an idea of what the problem might be.  If a conditional statement seems to not be working, print the variables being compared, You can stop a long *chain* of prints in a loop with ```ctrl-c```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an integer in `Array[0]`. this will never be equal to `'2'`. this may fix it:

```
Array[0] = str(int(Array[0]) + 1)
```

you may also want to have a look at the itertools module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations .

this does not exactly what your code does but might be worth considering as a starting point:

```
from itertools import combinations

values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

for a, b, c in combinations(values, 3):
    print(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Your solution fix it thanks. I have one more question tho...Prior i posted my problem i had tried to do this:
"Array[0] = int(Array[0]) + 1
str(Array[0])"

Instead of your solution...what is the difference? Why mine does not work but yours does?

Comment: i can't really parse your code... writing `Array[0] = str(Array[0])` after incrementing should do the exact same thing i posted. but if your statement was just `str(Array[0])` in the line after incrementing, then nothing happens. there is no assignment...

Comment: Yes, i did str(Array[0]) after incrementing but the loop didn't stop..that's what i find incomprehensible in this xD...but well at least now i know what my options are. Thanks for all the help :D